# Check if has pages?

Tags: pages, menus, conditional-content

So hard to find this info...

I'd like to know a way to find out if there are pages. Something like:

```
if (has_pages()) { /* do something */ }
```

I can't find a reference to any similar function... how might one go about finding out if there are pages. In case yr wondering I'd like to only show a pages menu if there are pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use `wp_list_pages()` ([Codex ref](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages)):

```
<?php
$has_pages = wp_list_pages( array( 'echo' => false ) );

if ( $has_pages ) {
    // There are pages; do something
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try using `wp_count_posts`, which will return an object with post statuses as properties. For example:

```
$count_pages = wp_count_posts( 'page' );
if ( $count_pages->publish > 0) {
   /* do something */
}
```

If you want to count all of the various statuses together, I imagine you'd just have to do a little addition before doing the compare.

Comment: That's some great lateral thinking there. Does it seem strange to you there is not a function already handling this scenario?

Comment: I personally think `wp_count_posts` is pretty much right on, though maybe it would be nice if it came with an "all" property :)